# QGIS raster clip error: Cutline not of polygon type

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a raster file and want to clip it, but I'm getting this error:

"ERROR: Cutline not of polygon type"

what does this error mean and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot, or share the polygon layer? The error message suggests it is not closed, or self-intersecting.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I verified both layers have the same projection info. Did you find another solution or possible cause?

Answer (score 1):

Please see this post.

[Receiving GDAL Clipper Error from QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177498/receiving-gdal-clipper-error-from-qgis)

1) One of the layers is missing projection information. Post both your layers so we can take a look.

2) A polygon that has some issues such as self intersecting (unlikely). It is almost always one. You need to project or project both layers into a common format.

Answer (score 0):

Is your polygon and raster in the same projection? If not, try projecting to a common projection, as mentioned here:

[Raster file clipping error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/32492/21406).