# Receiving GDAL Clipper Error from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gdal, clip, extract-by-mask

I realise there has been quite a lot of discussion on this topic and have already read through the suggestions on this forum of how to rectify this problem, but still nothing has worked.

I am trying to clip a merged hillshade raster using a vector mask to define the clipped area.  I have turned on-the-fly-projection off and both layers align to the same CRS.  I am still getting the error message "cannot compute bounding box of cutline".

I have tried all the suggestions in previous posts, but nothing works!  This is getting so frustrating!  Does anyone have any further suggestions on how to solve this problem.

I am using QGIS Lyon 2.12.3, but I also get the same issue in 2.8.6 LTR version.

A link to the zip files is given below:

[Attached Files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B651K_yfS3lNdXdvdEhMaHRZSGs/view?usp=sharing)

---

Also, when I clip using extents, it works no problems

Comment: Can you provide the shapefile for us to download (all parts in a zip file)?. I suspect your error is correct and you have a polygon with issues .

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [tour] because this site works differently to discussion forums and other Q&A sites that you may be used to.  When discounting previous Q&As (we don't call them threads - that's forum-speak) it is always best to include links to them so that we have a better idea of what you have reviewed.

Comment: I have provided a link to a zip file with the Geotiff and vector clip via google drive:

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B651K_yfS3lNdXdvdEhMaHRZSGs/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spatial reference of the tif is not defined. You will need to define it before proceeding with the clip.

```
C:\Users\frogman\Downloads>gdalinfo Hillshade_Wrap.tif

Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF

Files: Hillshade_Wrap.tif

Size is 9600, 15120

**Coordinate System is **

Origin = (1773760.000000000000000,5897760.000000000000000)

Pixel Size = (1.000000000000000,-1.000000000000000)

Image Structure Metadata:

  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL

Corner Coordinates:

Upper Left  ( 1773760.000, 5897760.000)

Lower Left  ( 1773760.000, 5882640.000)

Upper Right ( 1783360.000, 5897760.000)

Lower Right ( 1783360.000, 5882640.000)

Center      ( 1778560.000, 5890200.000)

Band 1 Block=9600x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray

Band 2 Block=9600x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

Clip extents (as the extents exist) would work in this scenario but not clipper or extract by mask as the polygon does not overlay the raster.An FYI, the raster has 2 bands.

Comment: I now seem to have solved the issues with the tiff.  Indeed the spatial reference was not defined in the tiff, even though it was referenced to the project CRS and it was all correctly aligned.  It required the reprojection using GDAL