# Cannot clip a raster excluding dataset

Tags: qgis, clip

I'm tryng to clip a raster with a shapefile using the tool in QGIS 2.18: Raster--> Extraction--> Clip.

Since **I want not only to clip the raster layer**, but **also clip the dataset** in order to have a lighter file (using the shape as a mask and checking the box "clip also the dataset" as you can see from the image [forgive me, in the image everything is in Italian]).

I tried to solve my problem with previuos discussion but nothing. In fact, the most similar was this one [Rasterfile clipping error: Cannot compute bounding box of cutline](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32394/rasterfile-clipping-error-cannot-compute-bounding-box-of-cutline), where the solution was to set the same CRS to the raster and the shape. I checked and it was the same CRS, but the error continued to appear.

If I try to clip the layer **without** checking the box for clipping also the dataset, it works.

Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: This may be an overkill, but will you save your input file (`OUTPUT_cum_curmap.asc`) as an GeoTiff file before this clipping operation? It will be a good opportunity to ensure your CRS, too.

Comment: Oh yes! (Sorry for the delay).
This is also quite strange but it worked. I mean, it is strange because the layer had its CRS, and also trying to assign it again (using raster-->projection-->assign projection) it didn't work. But doing has @Kazuhito said it worked.
First, thank you! Second, can you explain me why it happened?

Comment: To be honest I do not know why. There are occasions QGIS operations are influenced by data source, so I will convert KML to Shapefile and Ascii to GeoTiff whenever I encounter errors. Sorry I have no answer, but glad it worked out for you.